# Long polling - is reconnection important?

Tags: http, long-polling

I've read some articles about http long-polling, but I don't understand these 2 things:

- Why is recommended keeping connection open less than a minute? It should cause problems such as timeout or ..?
- Why I should reopen the connection after I've received data from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard that a long poll should be open for less than a minute. However, my first thought is that you may do that to detect if the connection has been dropped or to account for mobile devices switching between wifi and mobile data.

Your second question is much easier to answer, If you application is relying on long-polling to receive push notifications from the server, it will need to constantly keep a long polling connection open. Once data is sent from the server over a long polled connection, the request is completed and the connection is closed, which means you would need to open it again to receive another notification.